# DC motor on rectified AC voltage

Tags: diodes

I recently built a 12 V AC rectifier to DC using a 220 V/12 V transformer. I just connected a diode bridge and a capacitor in parallel to give the DC output. But when I connected a 12 V DC motor(automotive AC blower), in just minutes the diode had heat up and wires were burning.

What was the cause of the heat and how can I get away with it in my circuit?

Comment: please post your schematic and ratings of motor

Comment: it is the usual schematic diagram in physics text books that i refered to. just that my load is a dc motor.

Comment: please share the diode part number you used

Comment: motor details also

Comment: the heat is caused by the electric current that is passing through the circuit ..... you do not do away with the electric current, because then the motor would not turn ..... you have to design your circuit to handle the current without overheating

Comment: i am trying to build a simple blower fun from a pajero air conditioning blower motor, its 12V. but i wanted to eliminate a battery since i have mains supply at home. i bought the diode (RS8), and a 10 micro Farrad capacitor from a shop and i was told it will work for a 12V load. it worked only for one day, only finding wires burnt up and capacitor terminals worn off inside the casing. but the diode is still working. So i am seeking for a solution because this was my first project but it was a success for only a day i was praised by grandma

Answer (score 1):

Maximum probable error:

you are using some under current rated diodes for high current application.

please try to put higher current rating diodes.

if you can provide more details.. schematic and load specifications

i can suggest you in detail

Comment: Please capitalise and punctuate properly. See site rules [Writing to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A 12-volt AC supply with a full-wave bridge and a capacitor will provide up to 18 volts depending on the value of capacitance and the load current. When supplied with 12 to 15 volts, the blower will probably draw 10 to 20 amps. Either the wiring is not adequate for the current or the motor is defective. The wires could be too thin or the connections might not be adequate. Did you solder the connections? You need a voltmeter and an ammeter to properly evaluate the problem. You could use a multimeter, but most multimeters can not measure more than 10 or 15 amps, that may not be high enough.

Comment: Mr. Charles, thanks for the advise. My mind is opened. Because I had used a former from an inverter and it had thin and weak wires. Also i realised that the shop I went to had home appliance electronics. I checked on some site and I realized that I had to use wire of bigger gauge, and also to use a car alternator diode for better results as it can hold bigger current. Thanks much. Wait for results tomorrow.

Comment: The diode bridge I had used had max fwd current of 6Amps, and the blower carries approximately 10Amp according to my multimeter

Comment: If your transformer was connected to thin wires, it may not be suitable for your load current. It apparently didn't overheat in a few minutes, but it may overheat in a half hour or an hour.